# My data generator is not getting new data. Just gets same data each interation

Tags: python, keras, generator, data-generation

I have created a data generator in python/Keras to pull in filenames and labels in batchesize=5.  It is getting the same file names and labels every iteration.  I would like it to get new (succeeding) file names and labels each iteration.

I have looked at a number of examples and read the docs but cannot figure this out.

```
def datagenerator(imgfns, imglabels, batchsize, mode="train"):
    while True:
        images = []
        labels = []
        cnt=0

        while len(images) < batchsize:
            images.append(imgfns[cnt])
            labels.append(imglabels[cnt])
            cnt=cnt+1

        #for ii in range(batchsize):
        #    #img = np.load(imgfns[ii])
        #    #images.append(img)
        #    images.append(imgfns[ii])
        #    labels.append(imglabels[ii])

        #for image, label in zip(imgfns, imglabels):
        #    #img = np.load(image)
        #    #images.append(img)
        #    images.append(image)
        #    labels.append(label)

        print(images)
        print(labels)
        print('********** cnt = ', cnt)
        yield images, labels
```

```
train_gen = datagenerator(train_uxo_scrap, train_uxo_scrap_labels, batchsize=BS)

valid_gen = datagenerator(test_uxo_scrap, test_uxo_scrap_labels, batchsize=BS)
```

```
# train the network
H = model.fit_generator(
    train_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES // BS,
    validation_data=valid_gen,
    validation_steps=NUM_TEST_IMAGES // BS,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Here is an example of the outputs I am getting.  You can see that each time it goes through the generator it fetches the same data.  The first line after "Epoch 1/10", has 5 files names.  The next line has 5 labels (corresponding to batchsize=5).  For example, you can see in each output for the first file name is "... 508.npy" etc.  And the labels are the same for each iteration.

```
Epoch 1/10
['C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\uxo_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#508.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#1218.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#71.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#551.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\uxo_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#843.npy']
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
********** cnt =  5
['C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\uxo_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#508.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#1218.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#71.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#551.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\uxo_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#843.npy']
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
********** cnt =  5
['C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\uxo_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#508.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#1218.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#71.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\scrap_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#551.npy', 'C:\\Users\\jfhauris\\Documents\\xtemp\\ML GEO\\MLGeoCode\\FormattedDataStore\\uxo_48-81\\JBCC_Norm_Formatted_48-81_#843.npy']
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
********** cnt =  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting `cnt=0` every iteration.  You grab 5 filenames, yield those, and then the exact thing is repeated so you're always grabbing the first 5.  You want to change

```
def datagenerator(imgfns, imglabels, batchsize, mode="train"):
  while True:
    images = []
    labels = []
    cnt=0
```

to

```
def datagenerator(imgfns, imglabels, batchsize, mode="train"):
  cnt=0  
  while True:
    images = []
    labels = []
```

You'll also want to make sure `cnt` stays within the limits of your lists. So something like

```
while len(images) < batchsize and cnt < len(imgfns):
  # blah
```